# How to write summarySE function in R

Tags: r

I'm a new R user and want to make a line chart with `std` using `ggplot`. 
For this I am using the `summarySE` function.

```
vrn1_summary<-summarySE(data,measurevar = "vrn1",groupvars = c("genotype","treatment","time"))
```

Since I cannot make my own function, I copied from the *R Cookbook* as follows:

```
summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                      conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE) {
    library(plyr)

    # New version of length which can handle NA's: if na.rm==T, don't count them
    length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
        if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
        else       length(x)
    }

    # This does the summary. For each group's data frame, return a vector with
    # N, mean, and sd
    datac <- ddply(data, groupvars, .drop=.drop,
      .fun = function(xx, col) {
        c(N    = length2(xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
          mean = mean   (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
          sd   = sd     (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm)
        )
      },
      measurevar
    )

    # Rename the "mean" column    
    datac <- rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))

    datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean

    # Confidence interval multiplier for standard error
    # Calculate t-statistic for confidence interval: 
    # e.g., if conf.interval is .95, use .975 (above/below), and use df=N-1
    ciMult <- qt(conf.interval/2 + .5, datac$N-1)
    datac$ci <- datac$se * ciMult

    return(datac)
}
```

When I call this function, it gives `sd` (standard deviation), `se` (standard error), and `ci` (confidence interval), but shows `NA` for `mean`, which is "vrn1" in my data and also shows warnings. 
From what I understand, this could be a problem in the `summarySE` function, but I'm unable to find out where/why.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. or guide me how to write a simple `summarySE` function?

Comment: Add those warnings to your question. As far as I understand, function from cookbook is the right thing, just that it doesn't work with your data., right?

Comment: Do any of your values in `vrn1` have the value `NA`? `na.rm` might be your problem although I'm unsure why it would just affect the mean and not the standard deviation.

Comment: no, there is no NA in my data

Comment: yes I think it just does not work on my data. I also confirm the class of vrn1 . First time it was factor but then i changes into numeric but still problem is there

Comment: I've recently rewritten that function so that it uses data.table rather than plyr, and you might want to try it: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hauselin/63366a2b60c4445648c559a8682204d2/raw/5e5489b537886eaeecaea7c307f8e2eabfa82fb1/summarySE2

Answer (score 0):

please check your data with

```
str(data)
```

I guess your measurevar **vrn1** is a **chr**.